# Ubuntu 18.04, boot from the usb, used refind, used without. No matter which options can't seem to get pased kernel panic

Tags: linux, macintosh

[image: Kernel Panic]

Trying to dual boot linux and have this issue no matter what.

Comment: What distribution? What version? How did you install? What have you tried?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, used etcher to put onto USB then boot from the usb, used refind, used without without. No matter which options can't seem to get pased kernel panic. Tried with a debian install etc...

Comment: Ok. Please would you put that into your question, where it's easy for people to see.